# Refreshing jQuery UI range slider whith new values

Tags: jquery, slider

I'd need a little help please.
I don't know how to assign new values to a range slider after reloading the page.

Here is the html:

```
<label for="slider-range-price1-value" class="adv-search-label-recherche-detaillee">Prix :</label>
<span>€</span>
<input type="text" id="slider-range-price1-value" readonly class="adv-search-amount-recherche-detaillee" name="slide_prix[]">
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<div id="slider-range-price1" data-min="0" data-max="<?php echo $prix_max ?>" class="slider-range-prix"></div>
```

and the js:

```
$(".slider-range-prix").each( function( index ) {
        var sliderId = $( this ).attr('id');
        $( this ).slider({
            step: 10000,
            range: true,
            min:  parseFloat($( this ).attr("data-min")),
            max: parseFloat($( this ).attr("data-max")),
            values: [ parseFloat($( this ).attr("data-min")), parseFloat($( this ).attr("data-max")) ],
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#" + sliderId + "-value" ).val( ui.values[ 0 ] + " - " + ui.values[ 1 ] );
        }
    });
    $( "#" + sliderId + "-value" ).val( $( this ).slider( "values", 0 ) + " - " + $( this ).slider( "values", 1 ) );
    });
```

I tried with this code:

```
$("#slider-range-price1").slider({
    values: [xxxx, xxxx],
});
```

But it doesn't work.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Hi, try this $("#slider-range-price1").val(90); this code is working for me

Comment: Hi Golda, thank you for your help but it still doesn't work for me.

Comment: Maybe because I put the code at the wrong place? Could you please check my page? http://www.chaylaimmobilier.com - it's the price slider which I'd like to be updated after a research.

Comment: Hi, $("#slider-range-price1").children().eq(1).css('left', '52%'); 
var a= 100-52;
$("#slider-range-price1").children().eq(0).css('width', a+'%');
$("#slider-range-price1").children().eq(0).css('left', '52%'); I have tried this code in browser console it works for me. It is a little bit lengthly solution, but it works